# Using Graph API, how do you search for onedrive files that end with either .abc or .def

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

How do you use the Graph REST v1.0 endpoint to search for OneDrive files that end with either - say - extension .abc or .def. I've tried a lot of variants including:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search?$filter=endswith(name,'.abc') or endswith(name,'.def')`

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='.abc' or q='.def')?select=name,id,@content.downloadUrl`

The search query for one extension works: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='.abc')?select=name,id,@content.downloadUrl`

Does two separate request need to be made to get files of both extension?

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, filtering with endsWith is not supported for OneDrive API. This really needs to be added soon to the API as this is a basic search requirement while working with files.

You could try **search for extension** however, it **sometimes returns non-matching files/folders** as it also searches for the content and metadata.

I think you need to do **client-side filtering**. However, this does mean you have to navigate through the pages to get a full list, but you will be sure about the result.